# Permission in docker Container just partly working with chown

Tags: docker, chown

I have a problem with access rights in a Docker Container. I am copiyng a folder from the host to the docker image into the folder `/var/www/html`. This folder has a deeper folder structure. Then, I want www-data which is executing apache to have access to the complete /var/www/html folder. I create the container with the following dockerfile.

```
#start with base Image from php 
FROM php:7.3-apache

#install system dependencies and enable PHP modules

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
      libicu-dev \
      libpq-dev \
      libmcrypt-dev \
      mysql-client \
      git \
      zip \
      unzip \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_mysql --with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd \
    && docker-php-ext-install \
      intl \
      mbstring \
      pcntl \
      pdo_mysql \
      pdo_pgsql \
      pgsql \
      opcache

#     zip \
#     mcrypt \

#configure imap for mails
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        libc-client-dev libkrb5-dev && \
    rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN docker-php-ext-configure imap --with-kerberos --with-imap-ssl && \
docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) imap   

#install mcrypt
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libmcrypt-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && pecl install mcrypt-1.0.2 \
    && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt

#install composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer

#set our application folder as an environment variable
ENV APP_HOME /var/www/html

#change uid and gid of apache to docker user uid/gid
RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

# enable apache module rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

#COPY Data to html
COPY --chown=www-data:www-data AppBare/ /var/www/html

#change ownership of our applications
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

#Copy file to start schema update on startup
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "/var/www/html/app/Console/cake schema update -y && /var/www/html/app/Console/cake migration && /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND"]

EXPOSE 80
```

After I create and start the container, I get the following error message accessing a website of the serving webserver. However it is also loading the website with images that were copied, so basically, the user has access to e.g. images, css and so on.

> SplFileInfo::openFile(/var/www/html/app/tmp/cache/models/demo_backend_cake_model_default_backend_dockertest_list):
>   failed to open stream: Permission denied

When I go into the console of the container and reset the permissions with the chown command, the problem disappears. So the command itself must be right. Also when I create a volume and mount the folder from the host to `/var/www/html,` everything is working fine.

How can I give the user the full access to the folder? I also tried out to switch give the access before I copy the data, but that's not working also.

Comment: Can you print the result of `ls -l /var/www/html` before you change the permissions manually inside the container ?

Comment: When I execute your code in the dockerfile it is saying `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root`.

When I look in the running container at the folder `/var/www/html/app/tmp` with the wrong permisson that cause the errors, it says `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root` the other ones like `/var/www/html` are `-rwxrwxrwx 1 www-data www-data`.

Comment: It seems like the permission is changing when I start the container. When I look at the processes, apachectl is running as root. Might this be a problem?

Comment: This is weird... i can't reproduce your error.. I have a simple docker file from the same base image and i have copied your lines `RUN usermod ...` `COPY --chown...` and `RUN chown -R...` and with that i have no permission problem.

Comment: Also apachectl is running as root because it is the default user when using docker. Unless you have a `USER` instruction in your dockerfile, which is not the case in your file, nor it is in the base image `php:7.3-apache`

Comment: When I look in the docker container, under `/var/www/html/app/tmp/cache/model/` I have 3 files. Two of them have `-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root ` and cause problems, another one has `-rw-rw-r-- 1 www-data www-data`. I am not manipulating it before. Can it be, that the files are created by the root folder somehow?

Comment: Okok, I did further research. The files in this folder are created by the usage of the system. The two files are created by the Entrypoint of the code `/var/www/html/app/Console/cake schema update -y`. So this is executed by the root user. Is it possible to say to execute this as www-data not as root? All other files that are create in the cache folder after time by the usage have www-data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About your last comment

> The two files are created by the Entrypoint of the code /var/www/html/app/Console/cake schema update -y. So this is executed by the root user. Is it possible to say to execute this as www-data not as root?

The answer is yes. You have to add the following line before your entrypoint :

```
USER www-data
```

This way, everything run after this line will be with this user.

Comment: Thats it. Thank you!